# Color change of string delimiter in listings with macro

Tags: pdftex, listings, color, code, css

**Problem:**

I have managed to get color highlight for CSS using the package `listings`, but there is a small detail that is not solved. The string delimiters are `:` and `;`. I would like the delimiter `:` to be coloured in blue, rather than the color of strings.

**Question:**

Is there a way to override the color of `:` in listings using a macro? All `:` should be in blue color.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Colors
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{editorGray}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0.2}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.35, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorPink}{cmyk}{0, 1, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorDarkOrange}{cmyk}{0, 0.8, 0.9, 0}
\definecolor{editorPurple}{cmyk}{0.75, 1, 0, 0}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  CSS
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\CodeSymbol}[1]{\textcolor{editorPink}{#1}}

\lstdefinestyle{css}
{
  stringstyle=\color{editorPurple},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray},
  keywordstyle=\color{editorPink},
  ndkeywordstyle=\color{editorBlue},
  identifierstyle=\color{editorDarkOrange},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray},
  sensitive=true,
  % Line numbers
  xleftmargin={14pt},
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  firstnumber=1,
  numberfirstline=true,
  numberstyle=\color{black},
  frame=l,
  % Keywords
  ndkeywords={color, text-decoration},
  morecomment=[l][\color{darkgray}]{//},
  morecomment=[s][\color{darkgray}]{/*}{*/},
  alsoletter={.\#},
  morestring=[s]{:}{;},
  alsodigit={-;:},
  literate=*{\{}{{\CodeSymbol{\{}}}1
           {\}}{{\CodeSymbol{\}}}}1
           {>}{{\CodeSymbol{>}}}1
}

\lstdefinelanguage{CSS3}{style=css}
\lstMakeShortInline[language=CSS3]^

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Code style
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\lstset{%
  % General design
  inputencoding=utf8,
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},
  basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily\upshape\lst@ifdisplaystyle\tiny\fi,
  frame=none,
  escapeinside=`',
  % Languages
  language=CSS3,
  % Code
  tabsize=2,
  showtabs=false,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,
  breaklines=false
}

\begin{document}

\noindent Inline CSS

\noindent ^.p { color: #ffffff; }^

\noindent CSS

\begin{lstlisting}[language=CSS3]
// Classes
.p { color: #ffffff; }
header > .nav {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Ids */
#test {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Desired output:**

To change the color of `:` from purple to blue.

**UPDATE 1:**

Thanks to @egreg, I found out a regular expression for switching out `:` to blue color, but I cannot seem to merge the new command with `\lstMakeShortInline[language=CSS3]^`. Any ideas?

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\colorswitch}{ O{editorBlue} m }
 {
  \css_colorswitch:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__css_colorswitch_input_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \css_colorswitch:nn #1 #2
 {
  % store the string in a variable for usage with \regex_replace_all:nnN
  \tl_set:Nn \l__css_colorswitch_input_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { ([:]) } % search a colon
   { \c{textcolor}\cB\{#1\cE\}\cB\{\1\cE\} } % replace the match with \textcolor{#1}{<match>}
   \l__css_colorswitch_input_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__css_colorswitch_input_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 2 (SOLUTION):**

Thanks to the amazing Sašo ([https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16819/sašo-Živanović](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16819/sa%C5%A1o-%C5%BDivanovi%C4%87)), there is now a working solution for this issue. This code allows both for HTML and CSS to be marked up inline and as code block. See minimal working example below.

Sašo's solution was to add the following to identify `:`.

```
\makeatletter
\def\colorcolonother#1#2{%
  \expandafter\ifx\the\lst@token:%
    \color{#1}%
  \else
    \color{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Then in the definition style of CSS added:

```
\lstdefinestyle{css}
{
  stringstyle=\colorcolonother{editorBlue}{editorPurple},
```

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Color definitions
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{editorGray}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0.2}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.35, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorPink}{cmyk}{0, 1, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorDarkOrange}{cmyk}{0, 0.8, 0.9, 0}
\definecolor{editorPurple}{cmyk}{0.75, 1, 0, 0}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  CSS
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Targets the colon in inline CSS code
\makeatletter
\def\colorcolonother#1#2{%
  \expandafter\ifx\the\lst@token:%
    \color{#1}%
  \else
    \color{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% Changes symbol colors for { and } in CSS
\newcommand{\CodeSymbol}[1]{\textcolor{editorPink}{#1}}

\lstdefinestyle{css}
{
  stringstyle=\colorcolonother{editorBlue}{editorPurple},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray},
  keywordstyle=\color{editorBlue},
  identifierstyle=\color{editorDarkOrange},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray},
  %
  sensitive=true,
  % Line numbers
  xleftmargin={14pt},
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  firstnumber=1,
  numberfirstline=true,
  numberstyle=\color{black},
  frame=l,
  % Keywords
  keywords={%
% CSS properties
  accelerator,azimuth,background,background-attachment,
  background-color,background-image,background-position,
  background-position-x,background-position-y,background-repeat,
  behavior,border,border-bottom,border-bottom-color,
  border-bottom-style,border-bottom-width,border-collapse,
  border-color,border-left,border-left-color,border-left-style,
  border-left-width,border-right,border-right-color,
  border-right-style,border-right-width,border-spacing,
  border-style,border-top,border-top-color,border-top-style,
  border-top-width,border-width,bottom,caption-side,clear,
  clip,color,content,counter-increment,counter-reset,cue,
  cue-after,cue-before,cursor,direction,display,elevation,
  empty-cells,filter,float,font,font-family,font-size,
  font-size-adjust,font-stretch,font-style,font-variant,
  font-weight,height,ime-mode,include-source,
  layer-background-color,layer-background-image,layout-flow,
  layout-grid,layout-grid-char,layout-grid-char-spacing,
  layout-grid-line,layout-grid-mode,layout-grid-type,left,
  letter-spacing,line-break,line-height,list-style,
  list-style-image,list-style-position,list-style-type,margin,
  margin-bottom,margin-left,margin-right,margin-top,
  marker-offset,marks,max-height,max-width,min-height,
  min-width,transition-duration,transition-property,
  transition-timing-function,transform,
  -moz-transform,-moz-binding,-moz-border-radius,
  -moz-border-radius-topleft,-moz-border-radius-topright,
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright,-moz-border-radius-bottomleft,
  -moz-border-top-colors,-moz-border-right-colors,
  -moz-border-bottom-colors,-moz-border-left-colors,-moz-opacity,
  -moz-outline,-moz-outline-color,-moz-outline-style,
  -moz-outline-width,-moz-user-focus,-moz-user-input,
  -moz-user-modify,-moz-user-select,orphans,outline,
  outline-color,outline-style,outline-width,overflow,
  overflow-X,overflow-Y,padding,padding-bottom,padding-left,
  padding-right,padding-top,page,page-break-after,
  page-break-before,page-break-inside,pause,pause-after,
  pause-before,pitch,pitch-range,play-during,position,quotes,
  -replace,richness,right,ruby-align,ruby-overhang,
  ruby-position,-set-link-source,size,speak,speak-header,
  speak-numeral,speak-punctuation,speech-rate,stress,
  scrollbar-arrow-color,scrollbar-base-color,
  scrollbar-dark-shadow-color,scrollbar-face-color,
  scrollbar-highlight-color,scrollbar-shadow-color,
  scrollbar-3d-light-color,scrollbar-track-color,table-layout,
  text-align,text-align-last,text-decoration,text-indent,
  text-justify,text-overflow,text-shadow,text-transform,
  text-autospace,text-kashida-space,text-underline-position,top,
  unicode-bidi,-use-link-source,vertical-align,visibility,
  voice-family,volume,white-space,widows,width,word-break,
  word-spacing,word-wrap,writing-mode,z-index,zoom
  },%
  morecomment=[l][\color{darkgray}]{//},
  morecomment=[s][\color{darkgray}]{/*}{*/},
  alsoletter={.\#},
  morestring=[s]{:}{;},
  alsodigit={-;:},
  literate=*{\{}{{\CodeSymbol{\{}}}1
            {\}}{{\CodeSymbol{\}}}}1
}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  HTML
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\lstdefinestyle{html}
{
  language=html,
  sensitive=true,
  stringstyle=\color{editorPurple},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray},
  keywordstyle=\color{editorPink},
  ndkeywordstyle=\color{editorBlue},
  identifierstyle=\color{editorDarkOrange},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray},
  tagstyle=\color{editorBlue},
  %
  markfirstintag=true,
  morecomment=[s][\color{darkgray}]{<!-}{-->},
  alsoletter={!-'},
  alsodigit={.:},
  keywords={},
  % Line numbers
  xleftmargin={14pt},
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  firstnumber=1,
  numberfirstline=true,
  numberstyle=\color{black},
  % Frame
  frame=l,
  % German umlauts
  literate=
  {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1 {\\-}{}{0\discretionary{-}{}{}}
}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Language and inline definitions for listings
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{style=html}
\lstdefinelanguage{CSS3}{style=css}
\lstMakeShortInline[language=CSS3]^
\lstMakeShortInline[language=HTML5]|
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Code style
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\lstset{%
  % General design
  inputencoding=utf8,
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},
  basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily\upshape\lst@ifdisplaystyle\tiny\fi,
  frame=none,
  escapeinside=`',
  % Languages
  language=HTML5,
  alsolanguage=CSS3,
  % Code
  tabsize=2,
  showtabs=false,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,
  breaklines=false,
}

\begin{document}

\noindent Inline CSS

\noindent ^.p { color: #ffffff; }^

\noindent Inline HTML

\noindent |<div class="test">This works well. Another.</div>|

\noindent CSS

\begin{lstlisting}[language=CSS3]
// Classes
.p { color: #ffffff; }
header > .nav {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Ids */
#test {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\noindent HTML

\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML5]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
  <head>
    <title>Comments in HTML</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- This is a comment -->
    <div class="test">This works.</div>
  </body>
</html>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```